# How to get reference or id for each item in custom ListView?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, custom-adapter

I have a custom ListView with following layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
        >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:background="#e0f3ff"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:id="@+id/answer"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

so my view is like :

```
 1. Q
    A
 2. Q
    A
 3. Q
    A
```

Now I want to bind click event in each 'Q' and according to that I want to change visibility of 'A'.Also I want reference for each question,answer and answer wrapper layout.I am using `custom adapter 'helpAdapter'`.

```
1.How can get reference of each question ?
2.How can I get reference like id or something else(unique) of each answer ?
3.How can I get reference of each Linear layout(wrapper of answer(A)) ?
4.How can I bind click event only in Question(Q) ?
```

Comment: if you have 100 questions will you you be having 100 rows. Instead have two textviews and replace the content with a new one. I think it is a better option

Comment: Use a ListView instead of a LinearLayout, and you will be able to reference each question

Comment: @verybadalloc he is using a listview. the question is tagged listview and custom adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ExpandableListView in your xml.set each group to Question(Q) and item group to answer(A)
this automatically show and hide child item when click on Q;

Answer (score 1):

Inside your list adapter, in the `getView()` method you can set an`onClickListener` to the `question` TextView. Then in the `onClickListener` you change the visibility of the answer (possibly with some kind of animation).

Comment: thanks, Can you please tell me, How can I get reference of each Linear layout(wrapper of answer(A)) ?

Comment: Inside the getView you create the view by inflating it. Then you can use `view.findViewById(R.id.panel)` to obtain it. However, I would go for the `ExpandableListView` solution as proposed by @surbiks. That will probably be a bit cleaner.